# how to deal with heroku code=H10 desc="App crashed"

Tags: heroku

hi folks I spent a whole day dealing with this ,I want to deploy my spring boot 2.4.1 blog on Heroku but returned H10 crashed, my app runs well on localhost8080.
please help me I really appreciate it.

```
2021-01-29T11:42:46.341298+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
2021-01-29T11:42:46.341299+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
2021-01-29T11:42:46.341299+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 42 common frames omitted
2021-01-29T11:42:46.341300+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-01-29T11:42:46.422599+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-01-29T11:42:46.460866+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-01-29T11:42:48.204095+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=blogfinal3454.herokuapp.com request_id=b35ff65c-f40e-4f24-927b-14757a2bd988 fwd="98.207.66.34" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-29T11:42:48.869148+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=blogfinal3454.herokuapp.com request_id=820aaa76-1b29-41c3-9803-2a79972c33e8 fwd="98.207.66.34" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-29T11:42:52.733599+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=blogfinal3454.herokuapp.com request_id=939ed6f3-7a5a-4c89-ae92-0cce9e33d3cb fwd="98.207.66.34" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-29T11:42:53.049943+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=blogfinal3454.herokuapp.com request_id=5eaf948a-73fa-487c-a3b6-aa9ce0bea5bb fwd="98.207.66.34" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: More context on what is your configuration could be appreciated.

Comment: here'is my github https://github.com/BigMango007/blog